# How to add JAR file to an existing WAR file web-inf/lib folder?

Tags: java, maven

My setup is the following:

- I have a **war** file that is not under my control (I can only pull it as dependency) which is a Spring Boot web application
- I have a **jar** file that I would like to add to **web-inf/lib** folder so that the war file sees it on its classpath

So far I was deploying the war file to my local Tomcat and added the jar to the lib folder of the Tomcat installation. I would like to switch to a single executable war file so that I can run it via command line and not using separate Tomcat instance.

How can I achieve my goal using Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the [overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) feature of the maven-war-plugin a try but I‘m unsure, if web-inf/lib is used by spring boot standalone executables

Comment: I don't have any web app, I would like to somehow overwrite the existing war by adding additional jars. I am not sure if overlays help in such case.

Comment: So you can create another maven module with war packaging, which takes the existing war and your jar and using the overlays feature to combine both

Comment: Ok, the resulting war file looks fine, however when I run it (java -jar) I get the following:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'WEB-INF
/lib/XYZ.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file

Obviously XYZ.jar is just an example here

Comment: recompressZippedFiles option doesn't seem to solve the problem - jars are still compressed

Answer (score 0):

Robert's suggestion was correct, I would like to summarize what exactly I had to do:

1. Use maven-war-plugin with an overlay pointing to the war dependency
2. Set up the plugin correctly:

   `<build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.3.0</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                     <archive>
                         <manifestFile>src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                         <compress>false</compress>
                     </archive>
                     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
       ...
       </build>`

I had to explicitly copy the manifest file (it was ignored) and disable jar compression.